# MVC: how to log the value of model's property in the controller's constructor, given that the model's property is fetched asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I am trying to apply MVC design pattern in my app.

However, I am not sure why the output of `this.logActivites()` in the `Controller`'s constructor is `undefined`. I can easily do `app.logActivities()` from the console after loading the page, though.

Is it because - for some reason - the data is not yet fetched? How can I fix that?

```js
class Model {
         constructor() {
             this.getActivities()
                 .then(json => 
                     this.activities = json.activities
                 )
         }

         async getActivities() {
             const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
             const response = await fetch(url)
             const json = await response.json()
             return json
         }    
     }

     class View {
         constructor() {}
     }

     class Controller {
         constructor(model, view) {
             this.model = model
             this.view = view

             this.logActivities()
         }

         logActivities() {
             console.log(this.model.activities)
         }              

     }

     app = new Controller(new Model(), new View())
```

Comment: How to fix it? By calling getActivities AFTER data fetch has finished? Why would you assume data fetch will do it's job in time = 0? What if some resource consuming job just started on the server (backup or something) and data fetch takes 10s?

Answer (score 1):

It logs undefined because at that juncture it is.
Here I show an example that logs `{}` so you can see that it is so.

I will leave it to you to rework for example what to do if your `fetch` never returns like `fetch("HTTPS://Iambadforever.gone/I/do/not/exist")`

I put in one possible change

```js
/*jshint esversion: 8 */
class Model {
  constructor() {
    this.getActivities()
      .then(json =>
        this.activities = json.activities
        // possibly this?
        this.logActivities();
      );
  }

  async getActivities() {
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const json = await response.json();
    return json;
  }
  
  logActivities() {
    console.log(this.activities);
  }
}

class View {
  constructor() {}
}

class Controller {
  constructor(model, view) {
    this.model = model;
    this.view = view;

    //  this.logActivities();
  }


}
let m = new Model();
console.log(m);
m.activities = {};
let v = new View();
console.log(v);
let app = new Controller(m, v);
```

Comment: This is a really fast post and likely other improvements need to be made